# Free alternative to Abyss Web Server X1

Tags: php, .net, asp.net

I did try to find a more suitable place for this question, and contemplated posting it on Server Fault, but since there's no real "fault" here, I chose to ask it on S/O.

Does anybody know of any free alternatives to the free Abyss Web Server X1 app, that actually work?

Comment: this question should be asked on serverfault.com , eaven it's not a "fault" as you say , check this link out maybe you'll find what you're lookiing for http://alternativeto.net/searchresult.aspx?search=Abyss%20Web%20Server%20X1

Comment: Awesome, I went to that site, and downloaded The Uniform Server. Looks pretty good. Fast, secure, supports all the latest stuff apparently. Will give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lighttpd is a good candidate, it is small, lightweight and supports CGI/fCGI. It works on Linux too, and supports ASP.net using mono/fCGI under Linux, OSX and Windows. PHP is also supported ;-)